# Rails 3 cookie.delete not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

Currently faced this problem in Rails 3.2.8 app, i have this call in my controller:

```
cookies.delete :cookie_name
```

But really no special cookie header issued by rails except `app_session`, so cookie is not deleted and just left untouched, adding domain has also no effect:

```
cookies.delete :cookie_name, domain: 'localhost'
```

**Update:** full code snippet:

```
class BuyController < ApplicationController

  COOKIE_KEY = :test

  def index
    @state = {}
    if cookies.has_key?(COOKIE_KEY)
      @state = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(cookies[COOKIE_KEY])
      # this has no effect!
      #cookies.delete COOKIE_KEY
      # currently use this as workaround
      cookies[COOKIE_KEY] = {value:''}
    end
    @configs = Option.all
  end

end
```

Comment: how are you deleting the cookie before sending the response or after response is sent can you paste the actual code where snippet

Comment: Thanks for paying attention, updated question with full code

Comment: Weird for my Rails 3.2.1 app the code work pretty well can u check (using your favorite debugging tool) is the delete cookie hash getting set after the `cookies.delete` command

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what do you mean by 'delete cookie hash' here ?

Comment: You still have the problem ??